# update query throws error in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, mysqli

I have a table named 'mostread' with 2 columns open_id(int) and read(int). Now the problem is if 'open_id' is already present in the table then i need to update the 'read' for every click else i need to insert a new row with 'open_id' retrieved from the controller and read=1. I am using the below code in my model which inserts a new row properly but the second time i click it throws an error as follows.

A Database Error Occurred

> Error Number: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'read = read+1 WHERE `open_id` = '193'' at line 1
>
> UPDATE `mostread` SET read = read+1 WHERE `open_id` = '193'
>
> Filename: D:/Xampp/htdocs/opunletter/opunletter/application/models/Select.php
>
> Line Number: 52

```
             public function click($id)  
      {  
           $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM mostread WHERE open_id='$id'");  
  
$count= $query->num_rows();
    if($count > 0) {
        $this->db->set('read', 'read+1', FALSE);
        $this->db->where('open_id', $id);
        $this->db->update('mostread');
        
        $data = array( 
   'open_id' => $id,
   'read' => '1'
);

$this->db->insert('mostread', $data); 
          return TRUE;
    }else{
         return FALSE;
     }
      }
```

Comment: `read` is a reserved word, wrap it with backticks https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/keywords.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding backticks arround `read` its a reserved [keyword](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/keywords.html) in mysql

```
$this->db->set('`read`', '`read` + 1', FALSE);
```

Comment: changed it to  $this->db->set('reading', 'reading+1', FALSE);.. but this is incrementing it +2 . 2..4..6..8...10 and so on